# addEventListener alternativa IE9

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo y en IE9 no me lo ejecuta...Cual es la alternativa para utilizar?

```js
 var but=document.createElement("button");
        but.className="action";
        but.innerHTML=ok[0];
        but.addEventListener('click',function(ev) {
            try{
             var divisi  = document.getElementById(id);            
             document.body.removeChild(divisi);
            }catch(Error){alert(Error);}
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addEventListener` está soportado en IE9 (fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/attachEvent)

> [1]: attachEvent() ya no está soportado en IE11+.
>
> EventTarget.addEventListener() está soportado en IE9+.

De todas formas, si quieres una alternativa para versiones anteriores tienes que utilizar `attachEvent`. Aquí tienes un pequeño hack para usar una u otra en función de la versión IE:

```js
var IE_version=document.documentMode;
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Trident")!=-1){
document.write("<h2>Internet Explorer:" + IE_version + "</h2>");
} else {
document.write("<h2>No es una versión anterior a IE11</h2>");
}

alert(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Trident")!=-1 && document.documentMode==8);

var but=document.createElement("button");
    but.className="action";
    but.innerHTML="Boton";
    addEvent('click',but,function(ev) {
        try{
         var divisi  = document.getElementById(id);            
         document.body.removeChild(divisi);
        }catch(Error){alert(Error);}
    });
  var d = document.getElementById("div");
  d.appendChild(but);
  
  
function addEvent(evnt, elem, func) {
   if (elem.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM
{
  elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
  alert("Estoy usando addEventListener");
  }
   else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
  elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
  alert("Estoy usando attachEvent");
   }
   else { // No much to do
  elem[evnt] = func;
   }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="div">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927637/addeventlistener-in-internet-explorer